# Python csv reader.next() vs next(reader)

Tags: python, csv

When reading files using the `csv` module, there are two ways to iterate through the generator returned by `csv.reader`.

```
with open('foo.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    row1 = reader.next()
    row2 = next(reader)
```

Is there any difference between how `row1` and `row2` are obtained? Is one preferred over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the beginning, the only option was to call `iterator.next()` on an iterator `iterator`. Python 2.6 introduced the builtin `next(iterator)`, which simply called `iterator.next()` under the hood. In Python 3, `next(iterator)` calls `iterator.__next__()`, and `iterator.next()` raises an `AttributeError`. So unless you are on a really old version of Python (in which case you should upgrade anyway), use the builtin.